# UILabel text is not getting changed which is in another class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two class

1. Timeline
2. Comment

in the **Timeline** class under every **CustomTableViewCell** represents a post and there is a option to comment on the post. To comment user has to visit the comment page which is **comment** class. When the user comments on it i wanted to pass that total comments count to **Timeline** page where it will display the comment numbers in the cell's **comment label**
So in my Comment class i did this when the comment is successfully posted:

```
TimelineViewController *t = (TimelineViewController *)self.navigationController.viewControllers[0];
            t.updateWill = YES;
            t.updateId = self.index;
            t.updateValue =(int)self.response.responseData.count+1;
```

and in my Timeline class under **cellForRowAtIndexPath** i tried this:

```
    if(self.updateWill == YES)
        {
            NSLog(@"YES YES");
        data.commentCount= self.updateValue;


        }
        else
        {
            data.commentCount = (int)data.comments.count;

        }
cell.commentLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d comments",data.commentCount];
```

**NSLog(@"YES YES")** indicates that the logic worked. Beside if i print the self.updatevalue it also shows me the correct result but the label remain as unchanged. What i am doing wrong ??

**Update:**

on Timeline class at viewDidAppear

```
(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [[ApiAccess getSharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
    [[[SocektAccess getSharedInstance]getSocket]setDelegate:self];
    [[[SocektAccess getSharedInstance]getSocket] reconnect];
    _chatSocket =[[SocektAccess getSharedInstance]getSocket];


    if(self.updateWill)
    {
        NSLog(@"viewDidAppear");
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.updateId inSection:0];

        NSLog(@"Update Value: %d",self.updateValue);
        NSLog(@"Update ID: %d",self.updateId);



        TimelineTableViewCell *cell = (TimelineTableViewCell *)[self.tableData cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];




        WallPost *data = self.myObject[indexPath.row];
        data.commentCount = self.updateValue;

        [self.myObject replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:data];

        WallPost *data2 = self.myObject[indexPath.row];

        NSLog(@": %d",data2.commentCount);

        [self.tableData reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [self.tableData reloadData];


    }

    self.updateWill = NO;
}
```

And cellForRowAtIndexPath in Timeline class:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    TimelineTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.counter = 0;

    WallPost *data = self.myObject[indexPath.row];

    cell.image.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    cell.image.tag = indexPath.row;

    if(self.updateWill == YES)
    {
        NSLog(@"YES YES");
        NSLog(@"Updated value : %d", (int)self.updateValue);
      data.commentCount= (int)self.updateValue;


    }
    else
    {
        data.commentCount = (int)data.comments.count;

    }
```

Comment: I don't see an issue here except that the data.commentCount could be nil.Can you print and check??

Comment: is cell nil ? Show code of how u r initialising the cell

Comment: it is to show the comment numbers. Its under cell so its cell.commentLabel.text @TejaNandamuri

Comment: put a breakpoint at cell.commentLabel.text, and try to print the cell description

Comment: no the cell is not cell as its showing other views correctly under cell @TejaNandamuri

Comment: @Fay007 Can you check data.commentCount.I think you forgot to initialize data model

Comment: Ahmad could be correct. the data should be nil !

Comment: Could you try NSLog(@"Updated value : %@", self.updateValue); below NSLog(@"YES YES"); line and post the output.

Comment: yes i have already did that and its showing me the correct value @Bharath

Comment: Can you please put in your entire methods for cellForRow and where you create *t? There could be a few things wrong, but more information is needed.

Comment: How are getting back to Timeline class and how is your cellForRow is getting called.

Comment: How bout the outlet of the label? Did you check it? Is it connected properly to the table view cell?

Comment: Ok, I think we need more of your code, try to add entire cellForRowAtIndexPath method & the code used in Comments class

Comment: And a small suggestion, Its recommended to use "DELEGATE" methods for passing data between viewControllers in your scenario.

Comment: check my update, as u will see from my viewDidAppear the cellForrowIndex is getting called, and cellForRowIndex is quite same